# How to show the actual values and not the index in the axis when drawing a contour plot from a netcdf file using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am exploring options to plot a contour plot in python from a netcdf file (which can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zGpDK35WmCv62gNEI8H_ONHS2V_L9JEb/view?usp=sharing). The file contains various meteorological variables at 1 hour intervals. I am trying to produce a time-height plot of wind (which appears in the netcdf file as 'u'). The following are the details of u:

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 u(time, height)
standard_name: eastward_wind
units: m s-1
_FillValue: -99999.0
missing_value: -99999.0
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (945, 30)
filling on
```

As you can see, it is a function of time and height. I am trying to make a contour plot as shown below:

[expected plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtCA8.png)

This is the code I have written for the same:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import num2date, date2num, date2index, Dataset

f = netCDF4.Dataset("Wangara_1hourly_data.nc")
u = f.variables["u"]
t = f.variables["time"]
h = f.variables["height"]

time = t[:]
height = h[:]

timedim = u.dimensions[0]
times = f.variables[timedim]
# print('units = %s, values = %s' %(times.units, times[:]))
dates = num2date(times[:], times.units)
print([date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for date in dates[677:702]])


# plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12.0, 8.0)

fig = plt.figure( figsize= (10,6))

plt.subplot(1,1,1)
contours = plt.contour(u[677:702, :].T)
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=10)
plt.title(u.standard_name + " (" + u.units + ")")
plt.xlabel(t.standard_name    + ' (' + t.units    + ')')
plt.ylabel(h.standard_name    + ' (' + h.units    + ')')
```

[Plotted figure using the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAaQq.png)

As you can see, only the indices are printed, not the actual values. I want to know how to show the actual values (and that too at 3 hour intervals) as well as how to show the hour values in the x-axis, so as to exactly reproduce the expected plot. Can anyone please help me?

I am using Spyder5.1.5, which uses Python3.9, obtained from Anaconda to write and plot the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have given time as x and height y to the contour method instead of hacking the labels on your own.

Here is a possible solution:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import num2date, date2num, date2index, Dataset
# ------------------------------------------------------------
f = netCDF4.Dataset("Wangara_1hourly_data.nc")
u = f.variables["u"]
t = f.variables["time"]
h = f.variables["height"]

time = t[:]
height = h[:]

timedim = u.dimensions[0]
times = f.variables[timedim]
# print('units = %s, values = %s' %(times.units, times[:]))
dates = num2date(times[:], times.units, only_use_cftime_datetimes=False, only_use_python_datetimes=True)
# ----------------------------------------------------------
fig = plt.figure( figsize= (10,6));ax = fig.add_subplot(111);
contours = ax.contour(dates[677:702],height,u[677:702, :].T)
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=10)
plt.title(u.standard_name + " (" + u.units + ")")
plt.ylabel(h.standard_name    + ' (' + h.units    + ')')
plt.show()
```

Notice, that I am giving additional values to `num2date` to get dates as `datetime` objects (matplotlib in my case is not supporting cftime objects).

The outcome is close to what you had expected:
[image]